# Supersized.js api error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, supersized

I have superzied.js 3.2.7 and jquery 1.10.1 with migrate plugin 1.2.1, in the firefox I get error:

```
TypeError: api.getField(...) is undefined
```

This line is:

```
if (api.getField('seed').indexOf('no_image.png') != -1) actual_width = '';
```

And the same problem in Chrome is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined.`

I have found this, but I have everything doing right: https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

the api.getField functio is defined in supersize.xx.xx.js and see as below(you need check if this function is marked disable or deleted on your supersize....js)

```
base.getField = function(field){
    return base.options.slides[vars.current_slide][field];
};
```